# Bind event on some row only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Actually, I bind a `dblclick` event on all tr of the table

```
$('#memberPaymentTableResult tr').bind("dblclick", null, memberPaymentSelectedRow);
```

Structure of my table:

```
<tr>    
    <td data-payment-id={{paymentId}}>{{paymentId}}</td>
    <td data-contract-id={{contractId}}>{{contractId}}</td>
    <td>{{replace price "." ","}}</td>
    <td>{{moment date "L"}}</td>
    <td data-status={{status}}>
</tr>
```

Is it possible to bind `dblclick event only on row where` data-status != COMPLETED`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is:

You can add common class to all tr which have data-status completed while creating html..so you can directly define dblclick event from that class

Second solution:

In dblclick event you can check if data-status is completed then return false;

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) with an [not attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) and add less events with event delegation

```js
$("#memberPaymentTableResult").on("click", 'tr:has(td[data-status!="COMPLETED"])', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

```css
.selected td { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="memberPaymentTableResult">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-status="xxxx">No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-status="COMPLETED">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-status="COMPLETED">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-status="xxxx">No</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#memberPaymentTableResult tr[data-status!="COMPLETED"]').bind("dblclick", null, memberPaymentSelectedRow);
```